# std::enable_if example in documentation

Tags: c++, c++14, enable-if

This question refers to the following documentation on `std::enable_if` and the example provided therein (for the sake of brevity, only relevant code segments have been reproduced in this question from the aforementioned example):

[std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

I have the following questions from the example usage code provided (request to refer to the documentation for the complete code):

1.

```
// #2
template<class T, class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_constructible<T,Args&&...>::value> //Using helper type
    construct(T* t,Args&&... args) 
{
    std::cout << "constructing non-trivially constructible T\n";
    new(t, detail::inplace_t{}) T(args...);
}
```

Which overload of the `new expression` does the above invocation of `new` conform to? It does not seem to conform to the following overload in the code:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t, void* p, detail::inplace_t) {
    return p;
}
```

In the documentation of [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), the following overload has been mentioned:

```
new(2,f) T; // calls operator new(sizeof(T), 2, f)
            // (C++17) or operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T)), 2, f)
```

Does the overload of the new expression used in the example code conform to the above? I would appreciate an explanation from anyone who knows.

2.

In the second overload of the `destroy()` method:

```
// #4, enabled via a template parameter
template<class T,
         typename std::enable_if<
             !std::is_trivially_destructible<T>{} &&
             (std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_union<T>{}),
            int>::type = 0>
void destroy(T* t)
{
    std::cout << "destroying non-trivially destructible T\n";
    t->~T();
}
```

how to read and interpret the expression:

```
typename std::enable_if<
             !std::is_trivially_destructible<T>{} &&
             (std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_union<T>{}),
            int>::type
```

Based on my understanding of the documentation on `std::enable_if`, I interpret the above to mean as "if T is not trivially destructible, and is either a class or union, with a public member of type int". Is this correct?

Comment: **1** Yes the invocation conforms to the overoad, as is clear from the article you cite. I'm not sure what further explanation is required. What precisely is unclear to you?

Comment: **2** Yes, this is correct. Perhaps more interestingly, if the condition does not hold, then `std::enable_if` doesn't have a member named `type`, the attempt to access this member is ill-formed, and the overload that necessitates such attempt is removed from overload resolution. That's the crux of SFINAE.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik detail::inplace_t{} has been defined as a struct, where as from the signature of the new expression overload, f seems to imply a function/method. That is where I perceive a mismatch. I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand. What is this `f` of which you speak, and why does it imply a function/method? Basically, if you have `new(something, something_else, whatever) T`, that calls `operator new(sizeof(T), something, something_else, whatever)`. The usual overload resolution is performed to find a suitable overload of `operator new`.